# Excel formula to populate from one column only if another is empty?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want column U to equal the value of column P. However, if column P says #N/A N/A then I want it to populate from column L instead. Is there a formula that will do this for me? Sorry if I've not explained it very well, I'm extremely new to excel!

Is there also a way of showing which column it has used?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Are you talking about a cell in `U` or `P`? Or the entire column? Have you done any research or tried anything yet? If you have, it would be helpful if you **[edit]** your question to include the formula you are trying.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)` should address the question in the title, for the benefit of others reaching this page.

Answer (score 0):

In **U1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNA(P1),L1,P1)
```

and copy down.

Note: the obvious `=IF(P1="#N/A",L1,P1)`  will **not** work!

Comment: This does not work for P1 saying #NA. In that case, I want it to use L1 instead

Comment: You only mentioned  **#N/A**  and **N/A** in your *Post,* not **#NA**

Answer (score 0):

While there is an NEI (*Not Enough Information*) flavor to your question, if the value column P is usually a number or date and you want the value from column L is column P contains **#N/A** or **N/A** or **#NA** or even an actual Excel `#N/A` error code then perhaps something like this would do.

`=IFERROR(--P1, L1)`

Please remember that we are not mind readers and our crystal balls are often cloudy. Some sample data together with the expected results goes a long way towards receiving a quick and accurate answer to your current dilemma.